# TextString evaluation leak

Tags: bugs, evaluation, string-manipulation, hold, conversion

**Bug introduced in 10.4 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

> [...] I checked and reproduced your issue, and have passed along a report to our developers on the same [...]
>
> CASE:3972929

---

```
TextString@HoldForm[1/0]
TextString@Hold[1/0]
```

[image]

Is this behavior expected? I failed to explain this with documentation, the more that it says:

> In other cases, expressions are formatted using InputForm

but:

```
ToString[Hold[1/0], InputForm]
ToString[HoldForm[1/0], InputForm]
```

[image]

The problem is the more important that `TextString` is a default `InsertingFunction` for a `StringTemplate`.

Comment: I am not sure, but could it be posible that $1/0$ is interpreted by MMA as a symbol `DirectedInfinity` and not as an operation?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas it could be but it is not the case because the message is issued.

Answer (score 8):

The case of `HoldForm` appears to by design, although the motivation for that design is unclear.  `HoldForm` should thus be listed as one of the special heads listed in the `TextString` documentation.  The case of `Hold` appears to be an evaluation leak, but maybe it is intentional for symmetry with `HoldForm`.

**HoldForm Variant**

A trace of the `HoldForm` variant suggests that the behaviour is by design.  Here are selected evaluations from the trace:

[image: selective trace of <code>HoldForm</code> variant]

The internal `ostr` helper function has definitions that explicitly strip `HoldForm`:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
GeneralUtilities`TextString`PackagePrivate`ostr //
    DownValues // Select[Not@*FreeQ[HoldForm]] // PrettyForm
```

[image: ostr definitions]

The documentation for `TextString` lists a number of heads that are treated specially -- apparently `HoldForm` should be added to that list.

**Hold Variant**

The case of the `Hold` variant is not so clear.  Here is a selective trace:

[image: selective trace of the <code>Hold</code> variant]

There are no definitions under any of the internal helper functions that explicitly deal with `Hold`.  A close inspection of the trace yields use of `Unevaluated`, which suggests that some attempt was made to prevent evaluation.  But this measure is defeated by later steps.

My guess is that there is an evaluation leak here, but perhaps it is just a happy(?) accident that results in a treatment for `Hold` that matches that of `HoldForm`.

**Motivation?**

Why would `HoldForm` be stripped when converting an expression to a string?  I have no idea.  It would seem that the ability to convert unevaluated expressions to strings would be valuable.  If it weren't for the explicit definitions on `ostr`, I would have called this a bug.  Now I guess I have to call it an inscrutable design decision.

*(This analysis is current as of Mathematica 11.2.0.)*